# How to chroot FreeRadius

Tags: chroot, freeradius

I have set up FreeRADIUS 2.1.12 on Debian for authentication in a WPA2-Enterprise environment. Now I'd like to jail it with `chroot`. There is a parameter in `radiusd.conf` configuration file pointing to the chroot location:

```
#chroot = /opt/jail/freeradius
```

But with the documentation inside of radiusd.conf I can't figure out what files and dirs needs to be inside the chroot directory.

I have figured out that I need `/var/run/freeradius`, `/var/log/freeradius` and the `/etc/freeradius` directory containing the configuration files and modules. Do I really need to put the latter into the jail or can they stay outside and be read on freeradius startup before the chroot is performed?
If not, do I need all files or only those being actually used in my deployment? As pointed out before, I am only using authentication features.

Has anybody done that before and can provide some details? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chroot is done after:

- Reading the main configuration
- Reading the module configurations
- Reading the virtual servers
- Reading the dictionaries

But before:

- Initialising modules. Which means things like the users file would need to be inside the chroot dir, as would any unix sockets, or other file based resources used by modules.
- Processing requests. Which means logfiles must be inside the chroot'd directory.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I figured it out step by step, works now. As we use certificates for authentication I needed to create some more directories, links and adjust permissions. Also devices null and urandom needed to be bind-mounted.

Comment: And in future versions of the server, the syslog socket too.